# Adding columns of matrix by row starting from 3rd row

Tags: r

I have a matrix and would like to get the sum of the columns by rows.

for example

```
a b c d e

1 2 4 6 9

2 3 5 3 2
3 2 9 8 5
```

I would like to add 1+2+4+6+9 and 2+3+5+3+2 and 3+2+9+8+5

An added complication would be that I would like to start from the 3rd column and add every second one.

So 4+9 3+2 and 8+5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the extraction of the matrix that you need, with the rowSums call:

```
rowSums(x[,-(1:2)][,c(T,F)])
## [1] 13  7 14
```